# Bindings problems with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, binding

I know it is a basic binding question, but I can not understand how it works with Xamarin. (So any links to a good explanation are more then wellcome).

I am trying to do a "Edit Ingredient Page" and I am trying to bind an Ingredient property to the html. I have 2 problems: 
1. The label named original does not show the Ingridient.ToString
2. If I change value of Amount and press Save button does not changed on the page previous to this ViewIngredientPage

What am I doing wrong?

I have the following definition of the class:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ViewIngredientPage : ContentPage
{
    public Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; }

    public ViewIngredientPage(Ingredient item)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Ingredient = item;
        DataGrid.BindingContext = Ingredient;
        UnitsPicker.ItemsSource = Ingredient.PossibleUnitsList.Keys.ToList();
   }

    public ViewIngredientPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataGrid.BindingContext = Ingredient;
        UnitsPicker.ItemsSource = Ingredient.PossibleUnitsList.Keys.ToList();
    }

    private void saveButton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
```

}
}

And the following definition of the Xaml page:

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="The original:" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Path=ToString }" x:Name="Original" />
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="Suggested:"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Path=ToString }" x:Name="SuggestedText" />
            </StackLayout>

            <Grid x:Name="DataGrid">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Label Text="Edit" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

                <Label Text="Amount:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Entry Text="{Binding Amount, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />

                <Label Text="Units" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Picker x:Name="UnitsPicker" SelectedItem="{Binding Units, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />

                <Label Text="Item" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Entry Text="{Binding Item, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"/>

            </Grid>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Text="Save" Clicked="saveButton_click" />
                <Button Text="Cancel" />
            </StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: first, you are setting the BindingContext for some individual elements, but not for the overall page.  Second, you can only bind to public properties.  ToString() is a method, not a property.

Comment: Yes, that what I wanted, to bind element to a context.

Comment: I did saw a binding to the method, but I can not understand why it does not working in my case

Comment: "in my case" - binding to a method is not supported.  You can only bind to public properties.